# How to get OSX Lion to remember app desktops between reboot?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

I got an iMac at my job and I do enjoy using it. I really like the multiple desktops, easy to switch as I'm used to the Ubuntu desktops, however. We have to shut down our computers overnight, just policy, and I select the 'remember my windows' and shut down.

However it seems that when you start up the computer it will open the apps into whichever is the current desktop, forgetting which ones I'd neatly organised them onto. I have three, comms, dev and other stuff.

Is there an app which will force applications to remember which desktop they are on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an extra app.

Here's how to do it (atleast on Lion):

1. Go to the desktop you want your application to start in.
2. Start the application
3. Hold down "ctrl" key from keyboard and click on the app icon in the Dock
4. New menu appears and from that menu go into "Options"
5. In Options, choose "This Desktop"

Next time you start that particular application, it will automatically start in the desktop you had it when you chose "This Desktop" ..

Comment: What about if you have multiple windows from the same application on different desktops? I have ten Chrome windows open across four desktops, I want them to reopen on the same desktop they were on after a reboot, but instead they all reopen on the first desktop.